# Facing error in pytorch v-1.1: "RuntimeError: all tensors must be on devices[0]"

Tags: parallel-processing, gpu, pytorch

I am using `nn.DataParallel()` for my `model` but facing an error.

I am doing something like

```
    self.model = self.model.to(device)
    self.model = nn.DataParallel(self.model)
```

If the device is `cuda:1` then I get `RuntimeError: all tensors must be on devices[0]`. 
But if I change the device to `cuda:0` the parallel training on multiple GPUs works with no error. I am wondering what the problem is.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I changed this: `self.model = DataParallel(self.model)` to this: `self.model = DataParallel(self.model, device_ids=[1,0])`
Now it is working fine. But if I write: `self.model = DataParallel(self.model, device_ids=[0,1])` the error pops up. If there are more GPUs, say 4, then write: `self.model = DataParallel(self.model, device_ids=[1,2,3,0])`